EF Core Query Limit Values Returned on Navigation Property
I'm building a query up before running it and trying to search something on the navigation properties. I can do that, but EF Core returns everything from that navigation property, when I'd like just the items that actually matched the criteria.
I believe that's due to the use of Any(), but I'm not sure how else to write this query in a way that works.
Here are the data classes (simplified):
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Place>? Places { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? StreetName { get; set; }
}

I start the query like this:
var searchData = 
    (from r in context.Table
    select new Record()
    {
        Place = r.Places.Select(x => new Place()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Address = new Address()
                        { 
                            Id = x.Address.AddressId,
                            StreetName = x.Address.StreetName,
                        }
                }
    });

Then I'm going through and building up the parameters based on what passed in to make the query. There's quite a few of these, but the relevant one is street name:
if (someCriteriaToSearchStreetName)
    searchData = searchData.Any(x => x.Place.Where(y => y.Address.StreetName.Contains(aStreetName);

This works in the sense that only row that matches it are returned, but every Address is returned even if it didn't.
For example, if I have 3 addresses and one matches, all 3 are returned. I want only the matching one to be returned.
I know that Any() is probably the source of the problem here, but I'm not sure how else to write this query in a way that works. If I wrote this in SQL as a JOIN I would only get the matching one, but I'm unsure how to translate that to Linq to Entities.
I'm using EF Core 8 and the Oracle Managed Client 21.
Thanks.

If i understand your question correctly, you have to use filter in both places: main record filering and child records filering.
var searchData = 
    from r in context.Table
    where r.Places.Any(y => y.Address.StreetName.Contains(aStreetName))
    select new Record()
    {
        Place = r.Places
            .Where(y => y.Address.StreetName.Contains(aStreetName))
            .Select(x => new Place()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Address = new Address()
                    { 
                        Id = x.Address.AddressId,
                        StreetName = x.Address.StreetName,
                    }
            })
    };


That looks like it should work, except I'm building up the query in multiple parts. So the first part is buildng the basic IQueryable, and then adding the part where I serach on the address is seperate on that IQueryable. That's because there's potentially multiple criteria and I don't know in advance which one to use. I'm not sure how to write this query while also doing that, which is what the question is really about.

With vanilla EF Core it is not possible, predicate should be injected into expression body. It can be done via LINQKit.
